# Disable automatic pregeneration of DAG?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, dag

I am working on a private blockchain (currently block #16117). I have pregenerated the DAG for epoch 1 as well. So, I started the geth instance with `--autodag=false`. However, I still get the following message when I start mining:

```
I0707 10:24:57.871976 eth/backend.go:452] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG ON (ethash dir: ~/.ethash)
```

I am not sure how to disable this. Is the `--autodag=false` command wrong? Is there a way to do this from the JavaScript Console?

> geth version - 1.4.9-stable

Comment: Why do you want to disable DAG Generation? out of curiosity.

Comment: @niksmac While mining my private blockchain, , automatic generation of DAG for epoch 1 started at block #16092. I had a lot of processes running at that time and the DAG generation failed due to low memory which ultimately stopped the mining process. So, I pre-generated DAG for epoch 1 and then started mining again. I want to disable this because I don't want the miner to crash while generating DAG for epoch 2 again.

Comment: Okay, so DAG is supposed to contain the previous work you have done to prove your work; PoW, so it has to recreate to match the new blocks in it. the way i do is to delete the chain data and start from block #1

Comment: Yes. Starting over from the beginning is a temporary solution but that would delete all the data, which is not desired. I saw this `--autodag` option in `geth --help` but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @variable I am facing with the same problem. My node has 2GB RAM, so due to the low memory while mining, DAG generation always fails and force me to remove /.ethash file, start mining and re-create DAG files from scratch. Does disable `autodag` solved your problem?

Comment: @Avatar Yes. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `--autodag` option to `false` doesn't seem to work. I typed this command in the JS console and it worked:

```
miner.stopAutoDAG()
```

Output:

```
I0708 11:01:29.112749 eth/backend.go:498] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG OFF (ethash dir: ~/.ethash)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the accepted answer...

The `--autodag` flag doesn't take a value, so it can't be set to `false`.

The DAG will always be pregenerated if mining is enabled from the CLI using the `--mine` flag. What the `--autodag` flag allows you to do is pregenerate the DAG even if mining is *not* enabled.

The pertinent part of the code is in [`flags.go`](http://AutoDAG:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ctx.GlobalBool(AutoDAGFlag.Name)%20%7C%7C%20ctx.GlobalBool(MiningEnabledFlag.Name),):

```
AutoDAG:   ctx.GlobalBool(AutoDAGFlag.Name) || ctx.GlobalBool(MiningEnabledFlag.Name),
```