# My node keep giving checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash) error

Tags: private-blockchain, dag

I have my private ethereum network. The way I started my geth:

```
geth --networkid 23422 --nodiscover --nat none --datadir="$datapath" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcport="8545"  --nodiscover --maxpeers=6 --bootnodes enode://$id@<ip>:<port> --autodag=false
echo 'miner.stopAutoDAG()'   | geth --datadir "$datapath" attach ipc:$datapath/geth.ipc console
```

My node does not do mining but it is connected the network. Blockchain is stop incrementing and halt on a number. My node gives following error:

```
I0314 09:32:13.387846 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
I0314 19:32:13.388103 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
I0315 05:32:13.388391 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
I0315 15:32:13.388641 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
I0316 01:32:13.388951 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
I0316 11:32:13.389214 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
I0316 21:32:13.389467 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
I0317 07:32:13.389720 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /root/.ethash)
```

I have to do `sudo killall geth` and restart my server. Then then node's blockchain sync with the original chain and everything is back to normal.

[Q] I have to check my node daily. How can I prevent this problem from happening? Could this problem related with `--autodag=false` flag?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure those messages are an indication of the real issue, but there's a potential problem with the flag you mention...

---

`--autodag=false` isn't doing what you think it's doing. It's actually doing the opposite.

The `--autodag` option doesn't take a value, so it can't be set to `false`. What you're doing by including it at all is actually the equivalent of setting it to `true` (because it will just ignore the `=false` part).

So by including it, you're asking the node to pregenerate the DAG, which isn't what you want, because you're not mining.

The `miner.stopAutoDAG()` is what you want to be using.

See [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11200/52) previous answer for more details.